# How can i add Array of images in imageview

Tags: iphone, arrays, image

```
-(IBAction)btnNextTapped
{

    self.currentPhotoIndex++;
    if([allPhotosArray  count]>0) {
        if(self.currentPhotoIndex>=[allPhotosArray  count]) {
            self.currentPhotoIndex=0;
        }  

        NSLog(@"====== allphotos in this county :%d",[allPhotosArray  count]);


        mugImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [allPhotosDict objectForKey:@"Photo"]]]];

    }
}
```

when i clicked next button , this method would be called, but when ever iam clickin on the next button the image should be change, but here iam not getting next image , 
Plese help me

Thank you in advance

Comment: why would not you store image data into array, instead of loading image every time from URL on tap next button.

Comment: what is allPhotosArray and allPhotosDict and pics comes from url or locally..?\

Comment: Do u want to retrieve image from given URL inside imageView?

Comment: Yes here iam geting images from webservices, by using xmlparser i have put the images into arry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to write following code in order to change images.

```
mugImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [[allPhotosArray objectAtIndex:self.currentPhotoIndex] valueForKey:@"Photo"]]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have all images into an array. So set one var that counts your click. Whenever you click on your button, just increase count of var by one and set that array index image into your imageview ....